# Encode Matrix Elements on register

Tags: circuit-construction, quantum-operation, quantum-circuit, oracles

I am trying to construct a circuit which makes the following encoding
$$O_H \left| i \right> \left| j \right> \left| z \right> = \left| i \right> \left| j \right> \left| z \oplus H_{ij} \right>$$
where $H \in \mathbb{C}^{N \times N}$ is a Hessian matrix and $n = \log_2(N)$ the number of qubits in the first two registers. The third register has sufficient qubits for the encoding up to a desired error.

Is there a way to do that?